# How to set first table column as bold (CSS)

Tags: html, css

I am a little rusty on CSS.

Problem 1: I'm trying to make the example table below. I want only the first column to always be in bold. Can anyone help me to get the td first-child argument to work?
Status: Solved... I had rows and columns mixed... pretty stupid error that passed my attention. - Thanks Ovokuro

Problem2: I have corrected the code  (in the snippet) but it doesn't seem to work on IE or Chrome. Can anyone tell why? Looks good to me and works on the online sim, but not when I save it in an html doc. First column doesnt show as Bold; and column width is off..

PS.: Can't add the styles in tags along the document as the rows will be created progamatically.

Please let's try to keep the code simple.

```css
table {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Optimum, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border-collapse:collapse
}
tr {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #A9A9A9;
}
td {
  padding: 4px;
  margin: 3px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  width: 75%;
  text-align: justify;
}

th {
  background-color: #A9A9A9;
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 28px;
  text-align: center;
}

td:first-child {
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 25%;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr class="firstrow">
      <th colspan="2">Sample</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
<tr><td>Line 1</td><td>Text</td></tr><tr><td>Line 2</td><td>Text</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Comment: Hard to know why it's not working for you. Is the CSS correctly linked?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Problem with Brownser Compatibility perhaps. It is working fine on Chrome.

Answer (score 10):

Target `td:first-child` instead of `tr:first-child`

Also, CSS declarations are terminated with `;`. The `<br>` element is used in HTML to produce a line break in text.

Also note that `td` will always be a child of `tr`, so you don't need to declare `tr td:first-child` in this case. Similarly, `tr` is a child of `table` so you don't need `table` either.

```css
table {
  font-size: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

td {
  padding: 4px;
  margin: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
}

th {
  background-color: #104E8B;
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: bold;
}

td:first-child {
  font-weight: bold
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr class="firstrow">
      <th colspan="2">Sample Table</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1st Column </td>
      <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I think OP put `<br>` while formatting the question but am not sure enough to edit.

Answer (score 2):

Just add `first-child` next to `td` so it looks like this:

```
td:first-child {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Also if you want to add a table class before (just for namespacing):

```
.table1 td:first-child{
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple. Exist many ways to do that. One way is Applying direct styles in the tag. I mean open a `style=""` property in the `<td>` tag. will looks like: `<td style="font-weight: bold">`